# Why CalledProcessError during subprocess.check_output(['cmd', 'arg'])

Tags: python, django, subprocess

I ahve django project hosted with Apache+mod_wsgi.I am trying to pull update using git command via subprocess, like:

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'mybranch'])
```

However, I am getting error like:

```
Command '['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'mybranch']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

This problem appears when I call this function via browser. If I run `subprocess.check_output(['git', 'pull', 'origin', 'mybranch'])` from python sell, there will not error. It works perfectly as intended.

Comment: could it be that `import os;print(os.getcwd())` (= the current working directory) is not in a git repository?

Comment: User it is in git repo

Comment: What is the output of the git command?

Comment: Maybe your path variable does not include the git command. Git could also loose your .ssh settings / the keys you need to access the ressource.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue twice with git grep.

It came the second time from the fact I forgot to add `www-data` to the group which has read rights on the git repository folder.

Also, as git command need to be run from inside a git repo, you may want to try by adding `'--git-dir='` and `'--work-tree='` in your argument list, just after the git main command :

```
   gd = '--git-dir=' + os.path.join(repo_path, '.git')
   wt = '--work-tree=' + repo_path
   gg_matches = subprocess.check_output(["git", gd, wt, "grep"] + gg_opt)
```

It is required if your cwd is different from your repo_path.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce this as the command works for me in the shell as well, but adding shell=True could possibly fix it when running under Apache+mod_wsgi

Comment: shell=True didn't fixed that. I doubt that it is user permission problem. When calling url, the script is run by www-data user

Comment: @Elisa Who owns the directory though? What is the current working directory when running under Apache? Do you really want to be making system calls from a web server?

Comment: I wasn't thinking permissions, but rather missing ENV variables.  GitPython could be worth a look at http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html, although you may hit up against the same issue

Comment: @AlexChamberlain the directory own user abcd, that I used to login to ubuntu machine. the path is same for while running from python shell, and web.

Yes, I am calling system calls from a web server.

Comment: @igniteflow I provided full path like /usr/bin/git, but it still do not work